# select at least one field have the value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table report with fields meeting_start_date,call_start_date and one more table which I want to join with another table dcalendar with the field value. now now able to select type from my query

```
select
    a.id,a.meeting_start_date,a.call_start_date
from
  report as a
left join
  dcalendar b
    on b.datevalue=a.meeting_start_date
left join
  dcalendar c
    on c.datevalue=a.call_start_date
where
  (a.lead_stage_c='test')
  and
  (b.datevalue > '2020-07-31' and b.datevalue < '2020-08-05')
  or
  ( c.datevalue > '2020-07-31' and c.datevalue < '2020-08-05')
  and
  type='test'
```

Report table
[image: report table]

```
dcalender
id datevalue
1  "2020-08-01 00:00:00"
2  "2020-08-02 00:00:00"
3  "2020-08-03 00:00:00"
4  "2020-08-04 00:00:00
5  "2020-08-05 00:00:00"
```

I want to select the rows in report table either meeting_start_date or call_start_date is which has the dcalender table dvalue is greater than '2020-08-01' and less than or equal '2020-08-04'.

from my example i need to select 1,2,3,4,5
tried as

what I did wrong in my query

Comment: Laying out a long query as a single line makes it near impossible to read, so I reformatted it for you.  Feel free to adjust the style, but please don't post single line queries.  As for a guess, you ahve the parenthesis wrong in the where clause.  Probaby want additional `()` around the two parts of the `OR`

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are off:

```
where a.lead_stage_c = 'Target-MQL' and
      type = 'test' and
      (b.datevalue > '2020-07-31' and b.datevalue < '2020-08-05' or
       c.datevalue > '2020-07-31' and c.datevalue < '2020-08-05'
      )
```

Comment: typo error insted of test even though not getting correct output

Comment: @user3386779 - Edit your question to include the changes suggested here and show the output you get compared to the output you actually want.  Phrases such as "not getting correct output" are unfortunately not helpful, we need more information...